# PLSQL: ORA- 00904 err "Invalid identifier" & PLS- 00487 error as Invalid Identifier & Invalid reference to variable 'i'

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, bulkinsert

In PLSQL block statement, DML operation will perform. I am using FORALL with BULK COLLECT. PLSQL statement mention below-

```
declare
 v_sub  tab_a%rowtype;
 v_res  varchar2(50);
 type v_rec_tbl is table of tab_out%rowtype;
 v_rec v_rec_tbl;
 cursor C is select b.sid, a.sin, 'N', SYSDATE from tab_a a, tab_b b;
begin
 open C;
 fetch C bulk collect into v_rec limit 1000;
 for i in (select a.sin from tab_a a, tab_b b where b.sid = .....)
  loop
  select * into v_sub from tab_a where sin = i.sin;
  end loop;

 FORALL i in v_rec.FIRST..v_rec.LAST
  insert into tab_out
  select b.sid, i.sin, 'N', SYSDATE from tab_a a, tab_b b where b.sid = ......;
 commit;
close C;
end;
/
```

When i execute above PL/SQL statement then getting error `ORA-00904` & `PLS-00487` at line `insert into tab_out` in `i.sin` as `Invalid Identifier` & `Invalid reference to variable 'i'`. 
How can i resolve this error so that record will insert fastly.

Comment: If you want to make that faster, don't use slow cursors, loops or PL/SQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, I want to make it faster but in `FOR LOOP` make it slow. Is ther any other way to make this PLSQL block statement as faster.

Comment: Then get rid of PL/SQL and the FOR loop completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `v_rec(i).sin`, not `i.sin`.

Although, you're saying that you'd want to make it run faster. Why did you choose approach that makes it *slower*? You use cursor, loops, ... whatnot.

Directly insert rows, without involving PL/SQL (unless necessary):

```
insert into tab_out (sid, sin, ...)
  select b.sid, i.sin, ...
  from tab_a a join tab_b b on ...
  where ... ;
```

Comment: Thanks for give me the answer. in line `for i in (select ...)` facing performance issue. Is thereany other way so that I can impove query performance.

Comment: You're welcome. As of performance, I already told you what I think about it. If possible, use a single INSERT statement, without any PL/SQL.

Comment: I used without PLSQL but taking time. I want to tune code in `FOR i IN (select ...)` becuase due to this taking more time.

Comment: Loop is often slower than pure SQL. It processes data row-by-row which is slow-by-slow. If I were you, I'd rather spend some time in tuning SQL itself. Make sure columns you use in WHERE clause are indexed. Gather statistics for all tables involved. Check explain plan.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the index on the collection `v_rec` as follows:

```
FORALL idx in 1..v_rec.COUNT -- changes here
  insert into tab_out
  select b.sid, v_rec(idx).sin, 'N', SYSDATE from tab_a a, tab_b b where b.sid = ......;
   -- see the usage of the idx
```